# Sql server error (DbEntityValidationException) when I try to save encrypt field in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I have table in database:

```
create table USERS
(
    iIdUsers int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    vNickName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,    
    vPassword nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    vEmail nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I have edmx database in project. I encrypt password field and try it to save this data in database. After that I have exception:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities.
>   See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Without encrypt, all is working good. Who knows what's problem with it?

My code to add new user in database:

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrEdit(USERS userModel)
    {
        using (NarkomDataBase dbModel = new NarkomDataBase())
        {
            PasswordEncryption encryption = new PasswordEncryption();
            Helper helper = new Helper();

            userModel.vPassword = Helper.ComputeHash(userModel.vPassword, "SHA512", null);

            if (dbModel.USERS.Any(x => x.vNickName == userModel.vNickName))
            {
                ViewBag.DublicateMessage = "Пользователь уже существует!";
                return View("~/Views/home/AddOrEdit.cshtml", userModel);
            }

            dbModel.USERS.Add(userModel);
            dbModel.SaveChanges();
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Регистрация прошла успешно!";

        return View("~/Views/home/AddOrEdit.cshtml", new USERS());
    }
}
```

I have two classes for encryption. 
Helper and PasswordEncryption.

Maybe sql server have limit for encrypt data?

Password before encryption: 123

Password afer encryption: 2ecggZEcNQ4qIMIHub8SJHQZ21aVzLRBBHG28v/YIFfWlHZjYNT+PTm4Jyes0Gh6GQIaAkenhMNsL/kx4C8+O6wGN1L2

Comment: Don't try to write your own encryption. MVC's encryption is far stronger than what you tried here. Your code is  wrong and *already* broken. There's no *salting* which means your passwords can be broken in less than 1 second using a rainbow table - a table with a large number of precomputed hashes.

Comment: If you can't save a field with the correct length, what makes you thing that you can write *authentication code* correctly?

Comment: Also, hashing just *1* time makes the use of rainbow tables trivial - in fact, .NET's SHA512 function is fast enought that one can break your passwords with brute force *alone*. Passwords are hashed *at least 1000* times before storage

Comment: Ok. So, what I need to do? How to save protect password in edmx database?

Comment: I can't get more information. Visual studio get me only this: `An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`

Comment: How to fix this: Remove all this code. Use ASP.NET Identity, it's built-in. In fact, when you create the project you can choose what kind of authentication to use. Start with the tutorials in [the ASP.NET MVC site itself](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security)

Comment: As for the error - did you *read* it? Did you *check* the `EntityValidationErrors` property of the exception object? Visual Studio does *not* "give you only this". When the debugger stops, it stops exactly where the problem occured. You have access to the Exception object through a popup window, the Autos and Locals watch Windows. You can check the exception and its properties. I'd bet the errors property explains that you tried to save a string that's longer than 50 characters, just as Nikunj Patel explains in the answer

Comment: I kniw. But field `EntityValidationErrors` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your password length after encryption is more than you defined in your table i.e.  `vPassword nvarchar(50) NOT NULL`

Which is less so You need to change it accordingly !!

Comment: It's not work. I have the same problem. I can't save encrypt field in edmx database